# how to calculate the average of dataframe of batches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

How do I calculate the average of dataframes created by batchsizes of csv file?

```
Input:
A,1
B,2
B,1
C,2
A,1
B,3
B,1
C,1
A,1
B,2
B,1
C,3
```

I want to group them by 4 rows (A,B,B,C) and calculate the average of 2nd column.

```
output:
A, average(1,1,1)
B, average(2,3,2)
B, average(1,1,1)
C, average(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the columns is named `label, value`, since you are averaging over a fixed number of rows, a reshape would be fine:

```
nrows=4

pd.DataFrame({'label': df['label'].iloc[:nrows],
              'value':df['value'].values.reshape(-1,nrows).mean(axis=0)
})
```

Output:

```
  label     value
0     A  1.000000
1     B  2.333333
2     B  1.000000
3     C  2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you all. Excellent answers but I had to pick one as answer.

Comment: how do I select another column to this? This didn't work.

`pd.DataFrame({'label': df['label'].iloc[:nrows],
              'status': df[;status'],
              'value':df['value'].values.reshape(-1,nrows).mean(axis=0)
})`

Answer (score 4):

First create a `cumcount` level for each separate batch that way you can separate the first 'B' from the second 'B' (assuming an 'A' begins each new group). Then group over the letter and this newly created group label.

Assuming your columns are labeled `0` and `1`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', header=None)

df['gp'] = df.groupby([df[0].eq('A').cumsum(), 0]).cumcount()
df.groupby([0, 'gp'])[1].mean()
```

---

```
0  gp
A  0     1.000000
B  0     2.333333
   1     1.000000
C  0     2.000000
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `groupby` them like this and then compute the mean.

```
df.groupby([df.index%4, df[0]], as_index=False).mean().rename(columns={0:'labels', 1:'mean'})
```

---

```
    labels  mean
0   A       1.000000
1   B       2.333333
2   B       1.000000
3   C       2.000000
```