# using pandas, how to calculate the mean of csv data in batches?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Adding more to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678416/how-to-calculate-the-average-of-dataframe-of-batches).

We want to calculate the average of dataframes from csv files that we read in batches. But sometimes, we might miss out a row or two in some batches.

Input:
Each group always start with A.
C is missing in 3rd batch.

```
A,1
B,2
B,1
C,2
A,1
B,3
B,1
A,1
B,2
B,1
C,3
```

output: print the mean of col2 and also count

```
A, average(1,1,1), 3
B, average(2,3,2), 3
B, average(1,1,1), 3
C, average(1,,3), 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in `df` dataframe

```py
df['gp'] = df.groupby([df[0].eq('A').cumsum(), 0]).cumcount()
final = df.groupby([0, 'gp'])[1].agg(['mean','count'])

#OUTPUT

          mean  count
0 gp
A 0   1.000000      3
B 0   2.333333      3
  1   1.000000      3
C 0   2.500000      2
```